# How create yui_patched id using click jquery

Tags: jquery, alloy-ui

How generate  new "id='yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1493708066807_175'" using click button

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Y.guid()` generates unique ids.](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_guid) You can generate a new id on button click like so:

```
Y.one('#buttonId').on('click', function(event) {
  var generatedId = Y.guid();
  // Your code here...
});
```

Here's a runnable example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/0214fdc4cccaa77d6e504320cf70a571/raw/63d260364730fb067f103c00862c7e65685256df/yui-3.18.1_build_yui_yui-min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Generate Id</button>
<div id="guid"></div>
<script>
  YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
    Y.one('#button').on('click', function(event) {
      Y.one('#guid').set('innerHTML', Y.guid());
    });
  });
</script>
```